# Pandas sort column but keep elements of the same category together

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns. One is numeric and the other is categorical. For example,

```
   c1   c2
0  15   A
1  11   A
2  12   B
3  40   C
```

I want to sort by c1 but keep rows with the same c2 value together (so all the A's stay together). In categories where there are multiple entries, we sort by the largest value in that category.

So end result would be

```
   c1   c2
0  40   C
1  15   A
2  11   A
3  12   B
```

How should I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can create a temp column with[`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) `max` to get the max value per group [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) with ascending `False` then [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the added column.

```
df = (
    df.assign(key=df.groupby('c2')['c1'].transform('max'))
        .sort_values(['key', 'c2', 'c1'], ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
        .drop(columns=['key'])
)
```

`df`:

```
   c1 c2
0  40  C
1  15  A
2  11  A
3  12  B
```

Comment: For your second approach, passing `kind='mergesort'` to `sort_values` keeps the order within groups intact. That way, you don't need to create a copy of the data.

Comment: I just realized that if there are two groups with the same max values, the second approach will fail.

Comment: `A` and `B` has the same sum, not max. `df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [10, 5, 15, 11, 15, 5, 40], 'c2': ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C']})` will fail.

Comment: Ah correct you are correct. Thank you @QuangHoang My first option would not have worked either without adding `c2` to the sort list (which it now is). I think it is now correct when two groups have the same max value.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = (
    df.sort_values(by='c1', ascending=False)
    .groupby('c2', as_index=False, sort=False)
    .agg(list)
    .explode('c1')
)
```

Comment: `groupby().agg(list)` is bad in term of performance. Not to mention this approach wouldn't work if there are other columns in the dataframe.

Answer (score -3):

`df.sort_values(by = ['c2', 'c1'], ascending = False)`